# AdWords traffic not (properly) reflected in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have an AdWords account, which was set to use Auto-tagging of URLs.

When looking at the Analytics account for that site, I couldn't find any reference to AdWords traffic either in the Advertising section or the Traffic Sources section.

So I manually constructed the URL tags, and updated the Campaign Ad. Once the ad was approved and the clicks started coming through again, I could see the results in the Traffic Sources section of Analytics. In the Sources > Campaigns section, my campaign was listed, and under Sources > All Traffic, it was registering the same level of traffic from `google/adwords`.

However, the Advertising > AdWords section is still drawing a blank. Any ideas? Are there explicit steps needed to enable full tracking of AdWords campaigns?

If it is relevant, the Adwords campaign was set up with one account, and the Analytics tracking with another, but both accounts have full access to both AdWords and Analytics.

Comment: Have you linked your AdWords and Analytics accounts? http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033961&topic=1308612&ctx=topic

Comment: I *think* I did - however, when I follow the process in your link, I get a 404 at the point where I click on the GA link in AdWords.

Comment: This sounds like you did not connect the accounts correctly. - Do you have the same e-mail address as an admin in both accounts? - Did you select "Data Sharing: With other Google products only" in the account settings? - After checking all this, did you enter Analytics via AdWords and connect the two in the Data Sources settings (Account level)

Comment: TBH Oliver... I've just left that employer so I no longer have access to their accounts.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ensure that you got accounts linked correctly.
2. Read the support article [Data Discrepancies between AdWords and Analytics on websites](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034383) as it explains whole issue in depth, so I won't repeat it whole :)